# Alphanumeric inputs to Amazon Lex slot via Amazon Connect

Tags: amazon-lex, amazon-connect

I am having troubles capturing user's alphanumeric inputs to Amazon Lex slot via Amazon Connect (voice) - for example - the bot can't completely capture inputs like A1234567B. Has anyone encountered the same issue? If so, may I know your approach on it?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it is simply an issue with voice recognition then I have used the methods below to make the string easier to get correct, depending on your use case:

- use the AMAZON.Alphanumeric slot type
- If the string is a set format as you describe above, create a custom slot type with many synonyms
- Capture the 3 elements separately: the first char, the number, the last char, then string them together
- Use the bot to capture the two chars and DMTF in Connect to capture the numbers